# wp_editor(), how to fetch content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress, tinymce

I got a wordpress page where users can add posts from the front_end. For this i use the WP_editor() function.

When I was trying the functions just plain in a new wordpress page I could just use

```
tinyMCE.activeEditor.getContent();
```

But now I'm setting everything up as the final product should look like, this means the editor is loaded in a modalbox (using fancybox plugin), and it initalizes fine, and it works. But I can't fetch the content the same way, it just returns me with the following error:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: tinyMCE is not defined
```

I assume this has something to do with the modal box loading the page in an iFrame, meaning the editor isn't there when the javascript code is running. How do I solve this? Can I bind it to something like .live() ?

Seems like such an easy problem, guess I'm just to tired to be thinking clearly today.

Best Regards.

Comment: Can you provide a URL of the page so we can see your markup?

Answer (score 2):

On the Front-End try to use `wp_enqueue_script('tiny_mce')` before.

Answer (score 0):

In the WordPress version I use the JavaScript object `tinymce` and not `tinyMCE`. Try using `tinymce`.